# Question on Furstenberg's proof

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

If Furstenberg wants to [proof the existence of infinitely many primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furstenberg%27s_proof_of_the_infinitude_of_primes), why he puts the set $\mathbb{N}$ ?  (Originally was $\mathbb{Z}$. But for simplicity I take $\mathbb{N}$)

Obviously, if $n\in\mathbb{N}$ $\Rightarrow$ $n$ can be $0$, $1$, a prime or a product of primes.

Then, in the last part, after creating the topology, he says: Suppose the set of all primes is finite...

But with this he can't write the set $\mathbb{N}$ at the beginning. Am I right?

It seems he's assuming the theorem is true for constructing the set $\mathbb{N}$. Is this valid?

Thanks

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is better, because it reduce the problem with finite cover.
I mean , if we consider $\mathbb{Z}$ without $\{-1,0,1\}$ then it's true that there is no finite cover. But for $\mathbb{N}$ it's not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to know anything at all about primes to construct the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$.

You can construct $\mathbb{N}$ with [Peano's Axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms), for example.

Then, once you have Peano's Axioms, you can use them to *prove* that if $n \in \mathbb{N}$ then $n$ can be $0$, $1$, a prime, or a product of primes (while you say it's obvious, that does not mean you don't need to prove it).